# Volume of Unusual Shape

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, volume

> Let $z = 1/r^n$, where $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $0 < n < 2.$ Note that this function has a discontinuity at the origin. Find the volume, $V(a)$, under this surface (and above the xy-plane) over the annulus: $a ≤ r ≤ 1$, where $0 < a < 1.$

This question has completely thrown me for a loop. I understand that this SHOULD be a triple integral, however, I can't figure out what to do with the n. It seems to me that this should also be integrated, however, this would imply a quadrupled integral, which we have not used in class and seems very unusual to introduce. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Do you know about the transformation theorem? In particular think about polar coordinates.

Comment: I've actually tried this question in cylindrical coordinates. Considering it involves an annulus, wouldn't that be appropriate? And no, I'm not aware of the transformation theorem, at least not by that name.

Comment: Actually you only have three variables.
$$V(a) = \iint_A z(x,y)\ \mathrm dx \ \mathrm dy$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $r \ge 0$, $z = r^{-n} \ge 0$. Thus the volume is
$$V(a) = \iint_A (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{-n}$$
Where $A$ is the annulus $a\le r\le 1$. Applying polar coordinate transforms to this gives
$$V(a) = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_a^1 r \cdot r^{-n}\ \mathrm dr\ \mathrm d\theta = \frac{2\pi}{2-n} [r^{2-n}]_a^1 = \frac{2\pi}{2-n} (1-a^{2-n})$$
Assuming $n\ne 2$. If $n=2$ we get
$$V(a) = 2\pi \int_a^1 \frac1r \ \mathrm dr = -2\pi \ln a$$

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this. If 0 < n < 2, then why do we simply keep it as a constant instead of integrating it across a region?

Comment: @Mock $n$ is a parameter. Your assignment constrains it to $0<n<2$. My solution allows for any sensible $n$.

Comment: Ah, I see, that actually clears things up quite a bit. Thanks a ton!